# Test Mail Server Tool

Tags: php, email, lamp

I've finally moved to Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows.
I had xampp installed for web development.

For testing of sending/receiving emails I used this tool http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/users-manual.html
Things were straight forward. I send email using PHP, it's saved and opened automatically in Windows Live Mail.
How can I achieve that in Ubuntu?

I currently have LAMP installed. Where to go next?

Thanks,
Fouad

Comment: What would you like to do? Send an email and check if it arrives at the destination? If so, use `echo 'This is a test' | mail -s "Hello test world" you@youremaildomain.com`

Comment: I would like to send emails from PHP, receive them locally to see how they are rendered

Comment: I also apt-get install sendmail
then apt-get install postfix
chose the local option in the config

Comment: There is a php mailer in github. You can adjust the code to your needs.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use MailCatcher:
https://mailcatcher.me/

An in my opinion better alternative is postfix with pcre to have a proper catch-all.

Setup a Local Only Email Server.

1. Point localhost.com to your machine

   Most of programs will not accept an email using just @localhost as domain. So, edit /etc/hosts file to make the domain localhost.com point to your machine, including this content to the file:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 localhost.com
   ```
2. Install Postfix

   ```
   sudo apt-get install postfix postfix-pcre
   ```
3. Configure Postfix to Local only.

   During postfix install process, the configure text dialog will display five options:

   General type of mail configuration:

   No configuration
   Internet Site
   Internet with smarthost
   Satellite system
   Local only

   Select "Local Only".

   For the domain name, use the default suggested and finish the install.
4. Configure a Catch-all Address

   Enabling this, you can use any email address.

   Example: here, my unique account is rael@localhost.com. But while testing systems, I can use any address like joe@localhost.com, foo@localhost.com, etc., because all will be redirected to rael@localhost.com

   If it dies not exist, create file /etc/postfix/virtual: `sudo nano /etc/postfix/virtual`

   Add the following line content, replacing with your user account:

   ```
   /.*/ <your-user>
   ```

   Save and close the file.
   Configure postifx to read this file:

   Open /etc/postfix/main.cf: `sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf`and check if this line is enabled, or add it if not exists:

   ```
   virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual
   ```

   Activate it: `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`
   Reload postfix: `sudo systemctl restart postfix`
   If you're under non-systemd distro, like Ubuntu 14.04, service restart command probably is: `sudo service postfix reload`
5. Install Thunderbird.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install thunderbird`
   ```
6. Configure Thunderbird.

   Skip the welcome screen (click in the button to use existing accounts);
   Click in the Settings button at top right (similar to Chrome settings) then click on Preferences > Account Settings
   Under Account Actions choose "Add Other Account"
   Select "Unix Mailspool (Movemail)"
   Your account will be @localhost (of course, replace  with your user account). Don't use @(none), use @localhost
   Outgoing server will be: `localhost` at port 25.
   Restart (close and reopen) Thunderbird.
7. Start your Mail Spool file

   This step have two purposes: test your install and stop the Unable to locate mail spool file. message.
   Using Thunderbird, send new email to @localhost, replacing  with your user account
   Click on "Get Mail"
   Test catch-all: send new email to averagejoe@localhost
   Click on "Get Mail" and you'll see the message at Inbox.

Comment: I found out about mailcatcher literally yesterday, part of the env for a client, looks great

Comment: about postfix way - thunderbird was dropped "Unix Mailspool (Movemail)" support, so it makes no sense now...

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured it out after a month! This is how it is done

1. Create a folder in your `Documents`  named `TestEmails`
2. Open the terminal and enter the following command

   `sudo chmod 777 ~/Documents/TestEmails/`
3. Open the `php.ini` file that is located in your `/opt/lampp/etc` directory
4. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and then type "`mail function`"
5. Under the `[mail function]` remove comment from `sendmail_path`
6. Set sendmail_path to    `sendmail_path = "cat > /home/USERNAME/Documents/TestEmails/date '+%Y-%m-%d - %H-%M-%S'.eml"` BUT MAKE SURE TO REPLACE USERNAME with your own username
7. If Apache is running, restart it

Comment: That's actually an interesting way of testing without having an e-mail server configured.

Comment: I think this is a better command `sendmail_path = "NOW=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d - %H-%M-%S'); FILE=/opt/lampp/htdocs/TestEmails/$NOW.eml; cat > $FILE;"` (make sure you have `binutils`)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postfix
```